# C#. Want to cache my database in memory and use the cache from more projects in same solution

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, caching

I want to cache my SQL Server database in memory and use the memory cache from more projects in same solution.

The problem is that I have a application used by 16000 users at the same time. Often there are problems with performance all related to database.

I use Entity Framework and want to use the model to create cached collections of all database tables.

Then `SELECT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` in memory and have threads do the real work of maintaining the data in SQL Server.

Is this possible at all? And if so, how?

Comment: the whole database in memory? Every time you create an `DbContext` instance it represents the whole database object.

Comment: The hole db. But only read it at startup. The changes will be to the cached model and the threads in background will maintain the actually DbContext Save.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a Windows service and communicate with it using WCF, exposing methods for your database operations.